# Linux Servers Patching - GCP

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I wanted patch my Linux instances, hosted on Google Cloud Platform.

Is there any native tool available on Google Cloud Platform, like Azure Update Manager, or do we have to use a 3rd party tool?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "patch"?  If you mean apply software updates, you can use the native Linux tools such as "apt update".

Comment: Yes, applying software updates and operating systems updates.

Comment: If the count is less, we can use "yum update", since i have centos 7 servers. But i have to do this every month and having 100 + servers. So i'm looking GCP native patching tools.

Comment: I think this might be what we are looking for ... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups   Can I ask you to review this and see if that is close to what you need?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [su] or [sf] or [unix.se], but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, At this moment GCP doesn't have a product that fulfills patch management like Azure update management. However, there are some other workarounds, on how to manage the patch updates of a large number of VMs.

a). Set up a startup script in order to execute certain maintenance routines. However,  restarting the VM  is necessary.  Startup scripts can perform many actions, such as installing software, performing updates, turning on services, and any other tasks defined in the script [1] .

b). If we want to patch large number of instances, a Managed Instance Group [2] could also be an alternative, as the managed instance group automatic updater safely deploy new versions of software to instances in MIG and supports a flexible range of rollout scenarios. Also, we can control the speed and scope of deployment as well as the level of disruption to service. [3]

c). We could use OS Inventory Management [4] to collect and view operating system details for VM instances. These details include operating system information such as hostname, operating system, and kernel version as well as installed packages, and available package updates for the operating system. The process is described here [5].

d). Finally, there's also the possibility of setting up automatic security updates directly in CentOS or Redhat 7.

I hope the above information is useful.

RESOURCES:

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript
[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#managed_instance_groups
[3] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups
[4] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/os-inventory-management
[5] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-os-details#query-inventory-data

Thank you all, who shared your knowledge!!!

Comment: It may not have existed when you asked this question 7 months ago, but GCP has an OS Patch Management service now that is specifically for scheduling updates for many VMs. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management

Answer (score 0):

GCP does not have any such package manager currently. If you would like to patch your servers you would have to setup a cronjob (either with crontab or another cron service like a GKE cronjob) to run the appropriate update command.

Comment: It may not have existed when the question was asked 7 months ago, but GCP has an OS Patch Management service now that is specifically for scheduling updates for many VMs. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management

Answer (score 0):

I think it was released after this question was asked (April 2020ish), but GCP now offers a native VM patch service called OS Patch Management for their VMs. You can learn more about it here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management